# Analogue of perfect field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative, unital local ring with maximal ideal $m$, and residue field $k$.  We can embed $k$ in its perfect closure by standard results.

My question: In general, for any such ring $R$, can we find a local ring $S$ such that:

1. Its residue field is perfect, and
2. There is a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ which is an injection
   ?

I ask because I'm dealing with local rings, and it would be handy to assume that their residue field is perfect.  (Or that they can be mapped via injections to rings which have this property).

Comment: Yes, you can use Bourbaki's notion of *gonflement*. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696720/116766). Note that [flat local maps are faithfully flat, hence injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4573964/116766).

Comment: Thank you.  This is super helpful